# Why does std::visit take a variable number of variants?

Tags: c++, std, variadic-templates, c++17, variant

Trying to get more familiar with C++17, I've just noticed [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
template <class Visitor, class... Variants>
constexpr /*something*/ visit(Visitor&& vis, Variants&&... vars);
```

Why does `std::visit` not take a single variant, but rather any number of variants? I mean, you can always take some standard library function and have it take multiple parameters with the same role, working on all of them (e.g. `std::find()` for multiple elements in a container); or you could be taking multiple visitors and using them on the same variant.

So, why this specific 'variadification'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we need to allow for visitation of *combinations* of classes within variants. That is, if we have

```
using Var1 = std::variant<A,B>;
using Var2 = std::variant<C,D>;
```

we can obviously use these kinds of visitors:

```
struct Visitor1 {
    void operator()(A);
    void operator()(B);
};

struct Visitor2 {
    void operator()(C);
    void operator()(D);
};
```

with `Var1` and `Var2` respectively. We can even use this next kind, with both `Var1` and `Var2` individually:

```
struct Visitor3 {
    void operator()(A);
    void operator()(B);
    void operator()(C);
    void operator()(D);
};
```

but what OP is missing is that we want to be able to visit one of the four pairs `(A,C)`, `(A,D)`, `(B,C)`, `(B,D)` - when looking at a pair of `Var1` and `Var2` **together**. That's why the variadic argument to `std::visit` is all-but-necessary. An appropriate visitor would look like this:

```
struct Visitor4 {
    void operator()(A,C);
    void operator()(A,D);
    void operator()(B,C);
    void operator()(B,D);
};
```

and we would call `std::visit(Visitor4{}, my_var1_instance, my_var2_instance);`

<sub>I figured this out when reading [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43812134/1593077).</sub>

Answer (score 29):

To make multiple visitation cleaner. Let's say I had two `std::variant<A,B>`, one named `left` and one named `right`. With multiple visitation, I can write:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(A, A);
    void operator()(A, B);
    void operator()(B, A);
    void operator()(B, B);
};

std::visit(Visitor{}, left, right);
```

That's a pretty clean interface, and is something that's pretty commonly useful. It's also easy to implement efficiently - you just create a *n*-dimensional array of functions instead of a one dimensional array.

On the other hand, with only single visitation, you'd have to write:

```
std::visit([&](auto l_elem){
    std::visit([&](auto r_elem){
        Visitor{}(l_elem, r_elem);
    }, right)
}, left);
```

That's miserable to write, miserable to read, and likely less efficient too.

Comment: So, I figured out the reason for needing `std::visit` to be the way it is by reading your answer, but you're kind of assuming I know the answer already. See my suggested answer below...

Comment: @einpoklum You figured out the answer from reading my answer, but my answer didn't help you figure out the answer?

Comment: It did (which is why I +1 you), but it only helped me figure out the answer, it was not _the_ answer.